# How do you connect directly to wifi access point without scanning? (wpa_supplicant)

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

How do I connect to an Access Point using its BSSID, SSID, and channel without scanning the network. I always connect to my home ADSL-wifi-modem and don't need to scan.

Instead what I'm seeing is this:

```
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484
wlan0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
wlan0: Scan completed in 1.264398 seconds
nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 1
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID 80:26:89:c3:6d:c2 SSID 'VivekM'
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 1 BSSID 80:26:89:c3:6d:c2 SSID '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
wlan0: BSS: Add new id 2 BSSID 00:f2:8b:42:33:f3 SSID 'AmwayMobile'
```

Comment: Please help by making the question more clear: What OS?, What have you tried? Where is that log from? Please edit question, so that we can know about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of scan is necessary to connect AP using `wpa_supplicant`.
Even if you already know the AP's information to connect to, the scan's behavior is required.
This is because `wpa_supplicant` compares with its own AP list when connecting.

The relevant parts of the source are shown below.
https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/events.c#n1140

```
if (check_ssid &&
    (match_ssid_len != ssid->ssid_len ||
     os_memcmp(match_ssid, ssid->ssid, match_ssid_len) != 0)) {
    if (debug_print)
        wpa_dbg(wpa_s, MSG_DEBUG,
            "   skip - SSID mismatch");
    continue;
}
```

Perhaps you are using `wpa_supplicant` with the `-dd` option to `debug` output.
You can check the related messages at the connection step with `enable_network`.